# MySQL. Queries. Unknown column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this following query and I want to display the results where masini > 2 but when I run the query it says that 'masini' is not an existing column but it's the name of a custom column I defined on the first row. I am new to MySQL.. can anyone point me in the right direction?
This is my query:

```
SELECT pers.serie_buletin AS persoana, COUNT(prop.serie_buletin) AS masini 
FROM persoana pers 
JOIN proprietate prop
ON pers.id_persoana = prop.serie_buletin
WHERE masini > 2
GROUP BY persoana ;
```

I defined the column on this line, in this part "COUNT(prop.serie_buletin) AS masini" but it says "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'masini' in 'where clause'". What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `WHERE` to `HAVING`.

```
GROUP BY persoana 
HAVING masini > 2;
```

> The MySQL HAVING clause is used in the SELECT statement to specify
>   filter conditions for group of rows or aggregates.
>
> The MySQL HAVING clause is often used with the GROUP BY clause. When
>   using with the GROUP BY clause, you can apply a filter condition to
>   the columns that appear in the GROUP BY clause. If the GROUP BY clause
>   is omitted, the MySQL HAVING clause behaves like the WHERE clause.
>   Notice that the MySQL HAVING clause applies the condition to each
>   group of rows, while the WHERE clause applies the condition to each
>   individual row.

[source](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx)

Comment: Three great answers but I'll mark yours as being the best. Fully explained and everything. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The where clause is evaluated first, so MySQL don't know what is masini there. Here are some similar questions.

[Getting unknown column error when using 'as' in mysql statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158605/getting-unknown-column-error-when-using-as-in-mysql-statement)

[Unknown Column In Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153598/unknown-column-in-where-clause)

As explained in the questions above and another answers here, you can only use alias from sub-queries, or in clauses that are evaluated after the alias is assigned as ORDER BY, GROUP BY or HAVING, in your case you can use the having clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT pers.serie_buletin AS persoana,
       COUNT(prop.serie_buletin) AS masini 
FROM persoana pers 
JOIN proprietate prop
ON pers.id_persoana = prop.serie_buletin
GROUP BY pers.serie_buletin
HAVING COUNT(prop.serie_buletin) > 2;
```

Comment: In the `HAVING` clause, which occurs after `GROUP BY`, you can refer to masini by name.

Comment: Ahh - I live in an Oracle world - Oracle doesn't seem to support that. Thanks for the information. Now I know mysql does!

Answer (score 1):

You can't put column aliases in the `where` clause.  Ever.

In this case, though, you actually need a `having` clause:

```
SELECT pers.serie_buletin AS persoana, COUNT(prop.serie_buletin) AS masini 
FROM persoana pers 
JOIN proprietate prop
ON pers.id_persoana = prop.serie_buletin
GROUP BY persoana 
HAVING masini > 2;
```